# Custom event trigger with YUI 2 imageloader javascript

Tags: javascript, events, yui

The YUI 2 imageloader library allows to create custom event triggers:

> You can specify custom events as triggers.
>   Call addCustomTrigger with any YAHOO.util.CustomEvent object:
>
> var myILEvent = new YAHOO.util.CustomEvent('anImageLoaderTrigger');
>   myFirstGroup.addCustomTrigger(myILEvent);

How do I trigger this custom event?

Answer (score 1):

```
myILEvent.fire();
```

As per the [documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.CustomEvent.html), the `CustomEvent` has a `fire` method which will notify all subscribers, namely your `myFirstGroup`.